# Como quitar los bordes en el modal header de bootstrap

Tags: php, css, laravel, bootstrap, modal

Buen día, estoy trabajando con laravel y bootstrap, ahorita estoy mas enfocado en el diseño, el problema es que al crear el `modal` me aparecen dos lineas blancas como si fuera un margen, hay alguna manera de quitarlas?

**Codigo**

```
<div class="modal fullscreen-modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="ventana1">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg " role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </button>

                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" align="">
                        <div style="font-size: 48px; color: white;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 " align="center">
                    <h2 style="color: white;">Encuesta Hello Survey</h2></center>
                        <center style="color: white;">Ten Feedback directo de tus usuarios</center>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br><br><br> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal-header{   
    min-height: 1px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0;
    margin-left: 0px auto;
    margin-right: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 0px auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px auto;
    background-image: url('img/FODNDO_PRODUCTO.png');
}

.modal-body {
   background-image: url('img/FODNDO_PRODUCTO.png');
}
.modal-backdrop {
   background-image: url('img/FODNDO_PRODUCTO.png');
}
.close {
    color: gray; 
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[image: Es basicamente lo subrayado de amarillo (perdon por tan mal edicion)]

Es basicamente lo subrayado de amarillo (perdon por tan mal edicion)

Comment: Comparte la versión de Bootstrap que manejas en tu proyecto.

Comment: version: Bootstrap 3.3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega `border: none` al header asi:

```
.modal-header{   
    min-height: 1px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0;
    margin-left: 0px auto;
    margin-right: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 0px auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px auto;
    background-image: url('img/FODNDO_PRODUCTO.png');
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Logre quitar el borde de abajo pero sigue apareciendo el de la parte superior, lo quite solo quitando el `modal-header` porque me di cuenta que solo usare el body, pero ya le pase los atributos por CSS al `modal-body` pero aun asi sigue apareciendo, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Aun quitando el `modal-header` te aparece el borde a arriba?

Comment: Si, aun quitando el header no desaparece.

Comment: me supongo yo que ya es cosa de la pagina o del sitio? porque igual hay una linea blanca que cruza toda la pagina, al estar intercambiando fondos me di cuenta

Comment: Alan gracias por tu ayuda me di cuenta que la imagen que crearon para este fondo tiene una linea delgada que no tiene color y eso hace que paresca que tenga algun borde, gracias compañero